# CMB details of wavelength, amplitude and frequency

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background

Hi could someone help me with a small project with the CMB signal. I need the details of wavelength, amplitude and frequency of the cosmic microwave background. Thank you from Marc.

Comment: How did this question change from a request for phase inverter change into a request for CMB details? On top of that, like all black-body systems, the CMB covers the entire spectrum; wavelength and frequency are just each other's opposites, and amplitude depends on your receiving antenna.

Answer (score 1):

You need an inverting amplifier, which can easily be made with any Op Amp. In the circuit shown in [this link](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_2.html), make sure that $R_{in} = R_f$ so that the gain of the circuit is -1.

Note that the Op Amp chip chosen must have a frequency response that is flat in the region you require, but most commercial Op Amps will easily meet that spec over the entire audio range. They can be purchased at any electronics component shop, via eBay, etc. Just search "buy op amp".

EDIT
In case you want to build it, here is a [link](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Inverting-op-amp-circuit.php) to an LM741 chip mounted on a breadboard. For a gain of -1, change the $1k\Omega$ input resistor to $10k\Omega$. You also need both positive and negative supplies. While the circuit specifies 10V, I think that 12V DC adapters are easier to find, and are perfectly suitable.